# Why uniform initialization syntax is applied only for objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

In c++11 we have nice uniform initialization syntax for objects. Why it does not extends to  initialize non-object types as well?

Is there any syntactic ambiguity for that, or is it just some stupid question I am asking?

Example:

```
struct s{ int k;};
s s1{1}; //ok (object initialization)
s const& s3{3};  //ok (object initialization)
s& s2{s1};  //error (reference initialization)
```

A more useful example:

```
struct t{ t(t const& x) : k(x.k){} int k;};
struct c
{
  c(t& x1,t& x2) 
    : s1_{x1} //error (reference initialization)
    , s2_{x2} //ok (object initialization)
   {}
 t& s1_;
 t s2_;
};
```

Another one :

```
template<class T>
T get()
{
   return T{};
}

//ok (object initialization)
get<int>(); 
//error (void initialization? I do not know terminology for void() token equivalent)
get<void>();
```

Comment: My guess is that the designers of the language decided that the existing `s1_(x1)` syntax is quite sufficient.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it clearly isn't (consider MVP).

Comment: Your last example is illegal. `void` is an incomplete object type; there is no way to create objects of type `void`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I agree that the `s1_(x1)` syntax and its implications are certainly annoying - they consistently trip up new practitioners, contributing to the perception of C++ as a "difficult language". Unfortunately, it is too late to change that in C++11: once a feature of this magnitude is in, it's in forever.

Comment: @Angew I guess void is not an object, as, `std::is_object<void>::value` is false. So there is no way to create void, just like you can not `create` reference. However c++ allows one to return void() token (And sadly not pass to parameter!), which looks like a constructor, but does not allow to return void{} as some token. And that is what I asked, which {} syntax is not for non-objects

Comment: `void` is an incomplete type and there is no way to complete it.

Comment: `void("hi there");` ... >_> ... <_< ... >_>

Comment: Regarding references: A const-reference can be initialized using uniform initialization syntax according to 8.5.4/3, 5th bullet point. It is initialized by creating a temporary and then extending its life-time. As for non-const-references, the bullet point that follows this rule says that a reference can be initialized from a single-element initializer list. As far as I understand this means that `s& s2 { s1 };` should actually be possible.

Comment: @jogojapan For non const reference gcc 4.8.1 says, `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 's&' from an rvalue of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'`. I do not know about clang

Comment: Yes, GCC fails. It does not fail when you use a simpler type (e.g. `int` instead of a struct). Still, in 8.5.4/3 it says: _[...] Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element, the object or reference is initialized from that element; [...]_ Admittedly, the rule before explains that for all references, a temporary is generated, and if the reference is non-const, the program is an ill-formed attempt to bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary. It's unclear to me why they put the rules in this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization rules of C++ are quite complicated.  They are described in the second half of chapter (clause) 8 of the standard.   There is zero-initialization, direct-initialization, value-initialization, copy-initialization, list-initialization to name just a few, and each can have different interactions depending on the context (declaration, parameter, return, throw, member initializer, etc), properties of the type to be bound and input initialization expression or braced-init-list.  The language designers also make it a goal to be almost backwards compatible with C and older versions of C++, which restricts what they can do.  It takes quite some study to speculate on the ramifications of changes to the initialization rules, and changes can generate a lot of unintended corner cases.  If you're interested I encourage you to study the standard and try to work through the implications of a proposed change you have designed.